# No Amazon Linux 2 in Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

When attampting to create a new instance on AWS Lightsail there is only the option for AWS Linux (2018.03.0) and not for AWS Linux 2.

Given that AWS Linux is end of support in December 2020, I'm a bit concerned that I cannot find AWS Linux 2 in Lightsail.

Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated:

It's available now. See @jeffmcneill's answer.

===============================

No, you are right. Amazon Linux 2 is not currently available in Lightsail. You can checkout the doc [here](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/compare-options-choose-lightsail-instance-image).

Comment: Thanks. Been hunting for that doc but couldn't find it.

Comment: Now available. As of Sep 24, Amazon Linux 2 is now available on Lightsail. The date on the image is 2.0.20200917.0 so it was released a week ago?

Answer (score 3):

As of Sep 24, Amazon Linux 2 is now available on Lightsail. The date on the image is 2.0.20200917.0 so it was released a week ago?