# Can't install CodeDeploy in Lightsail instance with Amazon Linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, amazon-lightsail, amazon-linux-2

As wasn't particularly satisfied with [only being able to use Amazon Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64143583/5675325) (wanted to use Amazon Linux 2 as well), created two instances using both OS versions and adding the same script

```
mkdir /etc/codedeploy-agent/

mkdir /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf

cat <<EOT >> /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeploy.onpremises.yml

---

aws_access_key_id: ACCESS

aws_secret_access_key: SECRET

iam_user_arn: arn:aws:iam::525221857828:user/GeneralUser

region: eu-west-2

EOT

wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/install

chmod +x ./install

sudo ./install auto
```

The difference I noted between the two is that in the instance that has Linux 2, the folder `/etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/` has only one file

[image: Amazon Lightsail Linux 2]

and in Linux has two files

[image: Amazon Lightsail Linux]

Knowing this, I created a new file in the Linux 2 instance with the same name

```
touch codedeployagent.yml
```

, changed its permissions from

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 261 Oct  2 10:43 codedeployagent.yml
```

to

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 261 Oct  2 10:43 codedeployagent.yml
```

[image: File permissions]

, and added the same content

```
:log_aws_wire: false
:log_dir: '/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/'
:pid_dir: '/opt/codedeploy-agent/state/.pid/'
:program_name: codedeploy-agent
:root_dir: '/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root'
:verbose: false
:wait_between_runs: 1
:proxy_uri:
:max_revisions: 5
```

[image: codedeployagent.yml content]

and then rebooted the machine. Still, this didn't fix the issue as when I run

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

will still get

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status codedeploy-agent.service Unit
> codedeploy-agent.service could not be found.

[image: Error remains]

Also ensured all the updates were in place, rebooted the machine but that didn't work either.

[image: Error remains even though updates are in place]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can provide details of my setup for Amazon Linux 2 instances to deploy  [CodeDeployGitHubDemo](https://github.com/tiago-peres/CodeDeployGitHubDemo) (based on past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151728/setup-codepipeline-deploy-step-has-a-status-of-failed)).

#### 1. CodeDeploy agent

Used the following as `UserData` (you may need to adjust region if not `us-east-1`):

```
#!/bin/bash

yum update -y
yum install -y ruby wget

cd /home/ec2-user

wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-east-1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install

chmod +x ./install
./install auto
```

It did not require hard-coding credentials. The following works perfectly fine on `Amazon Linux 2` instances that I've used.

#### 2. Instance role

Your instance needs a role suitable for CodeDeploy. I used an EC2 instance role with policy listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile.html#getting-started-create-iam-instance-profile-cli):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### 3. Deployment group

I had three instances for tests in an AutoScaling group, called `myasg`:

[image]

#### 4. Deployment

I deployed from S3 without Load Balancer:

[image]

#### 5. Results

No issues were found and deployment was successful:

[image]

And the website running (need to open port 80 in security groups):

[image]

### Update

For manual installation on Amazon Linux 2. You can `sudo su -` to become root after login.

```
mkdir -p /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf

cat <<EOT >> /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeploy.onpremises.yml
---

aws_access_key_id: ACCESS

aws_secret_access_key: SECRET

iam_user_arn: arn:aws:iam::525221857828:user/GeneralUser

region: eu-west-2

EOT

yum install -y wget ruby

wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/latest/install

chmod +x ./install

env AWS_REGION=eu-west-2 ./install rpm
```

To check its status:

```
systemctl status codedeploy-agent
```

With this you should get something like this

```
● codedeploy-agent.service - AWS CodeDeploy Host Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/codedeploy-agent.service; enabled; vendor prese
t: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-03 07:18:57 UTC; 3s ago
  Process: 3609 ExecStart=/bin/bash -a -c [ -f /etc/profile ] && source /etc/profile; /opt
/codedeploy-agent/bin/codedeploy-agent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3623 (ruby)
   CGroup: /system.slice/codedeploy-agent.service
           ├─3623 codedeploy-agent: master 3623
           └─3627 codedeploy-agent: InstanceAgent::Plugins::CodeDeployPlugin::CommandPo...

Oct 03 07:18:57 ip-172-26-8-137.eu-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting AWS Cod...
Oct 03 07:18:57 ip-172-26-8-137.eu-west-2.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started AWS Code...
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

If you run

```
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```

you'll get (meaning it's working as expected)

```
The AWS CodeDeploy agent is running as PID 3623
```

[image: It works!!]

To start if not running:

```
systemctl start codedeploy-agent
```

Comment: Just tested real quick to create two Lightsail instances in Virginia: one using the script you shared as start and the other not (and I ran it manually). In both reached the same error when running `sudo service codedeploy-agent status`. Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64040145/5675325) is having an impact

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 I don't have lightsale, but if its Amazon Linux 2 I don't see why would it be different.  You used my script in `UserData`?

Comment: in one instance I added it as a launch script (defined as «You can add a shell script that will run on your instance the first time it launches.») and in the other I ran the commands manually but in both hit the same wall

Comment: On the instance with my script, can you run `cat /var/log/cloud-init-output.log`. If my `UserData` fails, there should be an error message somewhere there.

Comment: I'm trying to update the question with that information but when I select all the text it shows "Connecting to your instance" and blocks from copying. Also installed xclip but it says `Error: Can't open display: (null)`. But i don't see any error in it though

Comment: just checked these steps again and got into a problem too big to describe here (so created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64176881/5675325)). I'm still wondering the reason Amazon Linux 2 leads to error when initially ran `sudo service codedeploy-agent status` and in Amazon Linux worked fine right away. But thank you for the insisting in the manual deployment without pipeline, I could visualize things better now by opening the application and seeing not only the groups but its deployments.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Thank for letting me know. So this question is still opened, or the CD was installed? Because without CD agent, your new question will also not work?

Comment: It's still open yes @Marcin

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 I updated the answer with new manual installation procedure for tests. Can you check it? Best to try on fresh instance, as existing one may already have some settings corrupted.

Comment: You rock @Marcin! That new updated script was what was missing. The difference was the way the /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf was built, not specifying the bucket name and including the env at the end too.