# The deployment to Lightsail instances failed because no instances were found for your deployment group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, amazon-lightsail, amazon-linux-2

Following from [Marci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170933/5675325), I went on and tried to deploy from GitHub using the steps he mentions (adapting the region) but I'm getting

> The deployment failed because no instances were found for your
> deployment group. Check your deployment group settings to make sure
> the tags for your Amazon EC2 instances or Auto Scaling groups
> correctly identify the instances you want to deploy to, and then try
> again.

[image: The deployment failed]

According to [Gabriel in 2017](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=246905)

> Lightsail is intended for smaller projects and doesn't support load
> balancing or auto-scaling groups at this time.

The only thing I could think of doing atm was to make sure each instance is using the tag `myasg` which is the same tag used in the Deployment Group

[image: Tagged instances]

[image: Deployment Group tags]

but that isn't enough.

Comment: If you can't select ASG in CD, you have to use Instance tags. Have you tagged. Can you show deployment group setting with tags? I can try to replicate the issue.

Comment: @Marcin just added that screenshot

Comment: The tags on Lightsale on the screenshot, do they apply to actual EC2 instances? Can you got to EC2 console and verify that the instances you trying to use have the tags applied?

Comment: @Marcin there's no EC2 instances involved, only Lightsail ones. Just confirmed and under EC2 instances there's nothing

Comment: Oh i see now. I'm reading this [post](https://noise.getoto.net/2020/04/23/using-aws-codedeploy-and-aws-codepipeline-to-deploy-applications-to-amazon-lightsail/). There is no direct support for CD and lightsale from what i see. You have to treat them as on-prem instances and use `register-on-premises-instance` to register them. This is what you are doing?

Comment: Similar info [here](https://scratchpad.blog/howto/how-to-use-codedeploy-with-aws-lightsail/).

Comment: @Marcin yes i've done the deployment [before](https://weblog.tiagoperes.eu/automating-apps-deployment-to-amazon-lightsail/). There was a difference after the creation of the instance in step 6. Verify the CodeDeploy agent depending if used Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux 2

Comment: So in this case i didnt manage to Register the Instances with CodeDeploy as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64170459/5675325)

Comment: On the first screenshot, there is "On-premises instances" menu option. Does your instance appear there? Does it have tags?

Comment: @Marcin it doesnt... most likely because i haven't really register the instances using AWS CLI

Comment: Have you tried? It does not work?

Comment: I'm about to try the other updated answer

Comment: Could you update the question with methodology used to register your LightsSale instance with CD, and any errors  if you get any?

Comment: I'm on my way to test this one now (in the meantime just had to go to the bathroom, hence the delay :P)

Comment: It works! You can write as an answer something within the lines, (1) SSH into the instance and [verify if codedeploy-agent is running](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170933/5675325), (2) In AWS CLI, run the following scripts (2.1) `aws deploy register-on-premises-instance --instance-name Amazon_Linux_2 --iam-user-arn arn:aws:iam::525221857828:user/Linux2CodeDeployUser --region eu-west-2`, (2.2) `aws deploy add-tags-to-on-premises-instances --instance-names Amazon_Linux_2 --tags Key=myasg --region eu-west-2`, (2.3) `aws deploy list-on-premises-instances --region eu-west-2` (3) Retry deploying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments:

Lightsale (LS) instances are considered as **on-premise** instances. This means that in order to use CodeDeploy (CD) with them, they need to be **registered with CD** as on-premises instances.

In order to do this, one can follow three steps:

1. Make sure that CD agent is installed and running on the LS instance. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170459/cant-install-codedeploy-in-lightsail-instance-with-amazon-linux-2/64170933#64170933) has details on the installation procedure.

[image: codedeploy-agent is running]

2. In AWS CLI, register LS instance with CD (Note that `Amazon_Linux_2` is the name of the instance)

```
aws deploy register-on-premises-instance --instance-name Amazon_Linux_2 --iam-user-arn arn:aws:iam::525221857828:user/Linux2CodeDeployUser --region eu-west-2
```

3. Add tags to the instance registered:

```
aws deploy add-tags-to-on-premises-instances --instance-names Amazon_Linux_2 --tags Key=myasg --region eu-west-2, (2.3) aws deploy list-on-premises-instances --region eu-west-2
```

[image: instance is registered as on-premise instance]

This means that now on the first OP's screenshot, there is "On-premises instances" menu option with the following

[image: Instance can be seen in on-premises menu]

Retry deployment if previous attempt failed before registration.

[image: Deployment worked fine]

and if you check your instances Public IP

[image: Instance public IP]

and navigate to it in the browser, you should see the result as expected

[image: Deployment using Amazon Linux 2 Lightsail instance]